# use caption of pressed button from main form in query of other form

Tags: ms-access, vba, byref, byval

My problem is:

Main form has 9 command buttons and continuous subform. Click on some button open other form with text box for entering quantity and two command buttons. When click on the first button I want to use caption of pressed button from main form for query. How to get that button caption?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have just clicked the button, you know the name of the control, so I do not quite see the problem, other than that it all sounds like quite a bad idea.

```
Private Sub cmdClickMe_Click()
Debug.Print Me.cmdClickMe.Caption
Debug.Print Screen.ActiveControl.Caption
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Remou. Your answer solved my problem. Forms!myFormName.ActiveControl.Caption is exactly what I looking for.