# how to go to a record in a subform within a horizontal form tab

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to reach the student ID within a form called `studentsFrm` embedded in a horizontal tab of the main form called `Home`.

So from outside the form, I need to call for a student number `x` and then the `studentsfrm` will go to this record.

`Home` form is open but the search for the student ID ( number ) is from outside the form, from another form.

Long story short, I need to open the main form (home), which contains a subform (`studentsfrm`) , pointing to a certain StudentID, the problem is, in the horizontal form tab, there is no child nor parent forms.

NB: I was trying to work with browseto I couldn't manage to find the right syntax, stuck in an run time error 6054, a valid path argument is of the form : `Mainform1.subform1` > `form1.subform1`

Comment: This method of submitting a question will not garner much help. Please supply code and examples

Comment: I think it's the common refer to subform issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36904595/referring-to-a-subform-from-a-query